# Publishing error in commiting phase in Tridion 2013

Tags: content-delivery, publishing, 2013

When i publish a Page in Tridion 2013 i get the following error:

```
**ERROR** DeployPipelineExecutor - Unable to start processing deployment package with transactionId: tcm:0-1011-66560
com.tridion.deployer.ProcessingException: Phase: Deployment Commit Phase failed, Commit failed for transaction: tcm:0-1011-66560, Unable to commit transactions, Commit failed for transaction tcm:0-1011-66560 because of Exception occured while trying to commit transaction tcm:0-1011-66560, The system cannot find the path specified, The system cannot find the path specified, Exception occured while trying to commit transaction tcm:0-1011-66560, The system cannot find the path specified, The system cannot find the path specified, Exception occured while trying to commit transaction tcm:0-1011-66560, The system cannot find the path specified, The system cannot find the path specified, Commit failed for transaction tcm:0-1011-66560 because of Exception occured while trying to commit transaction tcm:0-1011-66560, The system cannot find the path specified, The system cannot find the path specified, Exception occured while trying to commit transaction tcm:0-1011-66560, The system cannot find the path specified, The system cannot find the path specified, Exception occured while trying to commit transaction tcm:0-1011-66560, The system cannot find the path specified, The system cannot find the path specified, Unable to commit transactions, Commit failed for transaction tcm:0-1011-66560 because of Exception occured while trying to commit transaction tcm:0-1011-66560, The system cannot find the path specified, The system cannot find the path specified, Exception occured while trying to commit transaction tcm:0-1011-66560, The system cannot find the path specified, The system cannot find the path specified, Exception occured while trying to commit transaction tcm:0-1011-66560, The system cannot find the path specified, The system cannot find the path specified, Commit failed for transaction tcm:0-1011-66560 because of Exception occured while trying to commit transaction tcm:0-1011-66560, The system cannot find the path specified, The system cannot find the path specified, Exception occured while trying to commit transaction tcm:0-1011-66560, The system cannot find the path specified, The system cannot find the path specified, Exception occured while trying to commit transaction tcm:0-1011-66560, The system cannot find the path specified, The system cannot find the path specified, Commit failed for transaction: tcm:0-1011-66560, Unable to commit transactions, Commit failed for transaction tcm:0-1011-66560 because of Exception occured while trying to commit transaction tcm:0-1011-66560, The system cannot find the path specified, The system cannot find the path specified, Exception occured while trying to commit transaction tcm:0-1011-66560, The system cannot find the path specified, The system cannot find the path specified, Exception occured while trying to commit transaction tcm:0-1011-66560, The system cannot find the path specified, The system cannot find the path specified, Commit failed for transaction tcm:0-1011-66560 because of Exception occured while trying to commit transaction tcm:0-1011-66560, The system cannot find the path specified, The system cannot find the path specified, Exception occured while trying to commit transaction tcm:0-1011-66560, The system cannot find the path specified, The system cannot find the path specified, Exception occured while trying to commit transaction tcm:0-1011-66560, The system cannot find the path specified, The system cannot find the path specified, Unable to commit transactions, Commit failed for transaction tcm:0-1011-66560 because of Exception occured while trying to commit transaction tcm:0-1011-66560, The system cannot find the path specified, The system cannot find the path specified, Exception occured while trying to commit transaction tcm:0-1011-66560, The system cannot find the path specified, The system cannot find the path specified, Exception occured while trying to commit transaction tcm:0-1011-66560, The system cannot find the path specified, The system cannot find the path specified, Commit failed for transaction tcm:0-1011-66560 because of Exception occured while trying to commit transaction tcm:0-1011-66560, The system cannot find the path specified, The system cannot find the path specified, Exception occured while trying to commit transaction tcm:0-1011-66560, The system cannot find the path specified, The system cannot find the path specified, Exception occured while trying to commit transaction tcm:0-1011-66560, The system cannot find the path specified, The system cannot find the path specified
    at com.tridion.deployer.phases.DeployPipelineExecutor.runMainExecutePhase(DeployPipelineExecutor.java:197) [cd_deployer.jar:na]
    at com.tridion.deployer.phases.DeployPipelineExecutor.doExecute(DeployPipelineExecutor.java:97) [cd_deployer.jar:na]
    at com.tridion.deployer.phases.DeployPipelineExecutor.execute(DeployPipelineExecutor.java:61) [cd_deployer.jar:na]
    at com.tridion.deployer.TransactionManager.handleDeployPackage(TransactionManager.java:82) ~[cd_deployer.jar:na]
    at com.tridion.deployer.queue.QueueLocationHandler$1.run(QueueLocationHandler.java:175) ~[cd_deployer.jar:na]
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.7.0_25]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.7.0_25]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.7.0_25]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.7.0_25]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.7.0_25]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.7.0_25]
```

I checked all the paths in the config files but they seems to be there.
Can somebody point me in the good direction?

Answer (score 6):

For publishing errors like this, it's best to check out the deployer logs.

I do see that you have the following error:

"The system cannot find the path specified"

This could be caused by one or more of the following

- The incoming path in your transport config is incorrect
- The storage path in your storage_conf is incorrect
- You don't have a valid licence file
- The path specified to a licence file is incorrect
- The deployer doens't have acccess to read from the 'incoming' location

If you could post your logs so we can see the java exception, i'm sure you'd get an almost immediate answer on here.

Comment: Hi John,Thanks for the answer. Which logs do you refer at to see the java exception? And must the computername still match with the servername of the license?

Comment: The log files as configured in your app's logback.xml. Yes, the license must match the machine name.

Comment: The error above is out of the cd_deployer.log. All the paths i have dubble checked and the license files are ok. Also the path to the license files. How can i check if the deployer have access t the "incoming location"?

Comment: I would try to login to the machine with the same account that is running the deployer, and try to write a file to all the locations defined in your storage conf.

Comment: You can also use procmon to help troubleshoot file access issues http://stackoverflow.com/a/190858/1989431

Comment: Can you list down what "All" paths you have verified so far?

Comment: I am using the following paths: - c:\tridion\incoming (cd_deployer_conf.xml). - C:\inetpub\wwwroot\staging (cd_storage_conf.xml). - C:/tridion/incoming/transactions (cd_transport_conf.xml) For the licences i use: c:/Program Files (x86)/Tridion/config/cd_licenses.xml

Comment: @NunoLinhares Thanks. It is solved. The user had insufficient rights. I changed them and now the publishing action is succesfull!